# Change bootstrap navbar color back on resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am trying to change the background color for the navbar menu items for smaller screen sizes.

A problem arises when in the following scenario:

1. Browser window is made smaller until hamburger menu is shown
2. Hamburger menu is clicked to show menu items

(now my background color changes, which is what I want)

3. The browser window is made bigger up to the point where the hamburger menu dissapears

Now the background color does not change back to it's original. Can this somehow be fixed?

Below code demonstrates the problem:

```css
.navbar-collapse.show,
.navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've tried getting the colors to change back by applying properties to:

```css
.navbar-collapse.collapse,
.navbar-collapse.collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I guess somewhere it is overriden your code. I can see colors are changed if I use your last code of css. can you check if it is override? if not please provide more code. I am not seeing any issue in this code.

Comment: which bootstrap version your  using? And i dnt understand you question ,What do you what to achieve ?

Comment: Add a media query for large screen.

Comment: @Dhara when I use the last code with .navbar-collapse the colours change after the menu has opened. That's not what I'm after. When the menu opens in a small screen I want the background to be black. Then, when the window is made bigger, I want the background to return to it's original color.

Comment: @Amalnandan I'm using Bootstrap 4, but the issue is in Bootstrap 5 also as above code demonstrates. What I want to achieve is to have different colours for the menu items in small screens. That works, but if I make the window bigger when the menu is open, the background color stays black which is not what I want. When the window is made bigger with the menu open, the menu items should go back to their original colours.

Comment: @wazz I can see how that could work, but I prefer a solution without media queries, because then I would keep the media sizes synchronized with that of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .navbar-collapse.show,
    .navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link,
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing,
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: use media query for setting the width you can change the width size for every device

Comment: This works, thanks. Is there a way to format the media query so that it automatically syncs with bootstrap breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the CSS selectors, and set the @media query to the `lg` breakpoint of 992px...

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/J9TZrAnJCg

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I dropped the bit of code that I had and replaced it with:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .navbar-collapse.show,
    .navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link,
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing,
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
        background-color: #000000;
        color:            #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Turns out that you can't solve it with just css without media query because the classes don't change when you resize the window and the menu is collapsed or expanded. I did manage to tie it into the bootstrap breakpoints without hardcoding sizes.

Apparently this is scss, not css. I do have some homework to do on this subject, but at least now I have something that works for this project.

Thank you for all your help!